# Unable to traverse through a frame using web driver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, frame

I am trying to get the elements inside the second frame [here](http://prntscr.com/l8vy2k)

but I am getting the error that the element does not exist or the

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//frameset/frame[2]//a"}
```

I have tried every method out there but it does not work for me, this is my code

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://dps.psx.com.pk/");  

//switch to the mainFrame
WebElement mainFrame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frameset/frame[2]//a"));
driver.switchTo().frame(mainFrame);
List<WebElement> childs = mainFrame.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));

for(WebElement child : childs) {
    System.out.println(child);
}
```

I have also tried waiting for the elements to load and then tried to access the elements inside the frame but still same errors.

Comment: ```WebElement listedCompanies = mainFrame.findElement(By.linkText("Listed Companies"));``` on this line and on this line ```List<WebElement> childs = mainFrame.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));```

Comment: Don't change the question, it invalidate the answers. If you have a new question, post a new question.

Comment: that was a typo, I edited the question to add the correct information. If I ask the same thing it will become duplicate. @Guy

Comment: From `NoSuchElementException` it became `stale element reference`. It's not really a typo is it? You also changed the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `frame` locator is `//frameset/frame[2]`, the `//a` is a drill down into the `frame`.

You can also use the `name` attribute directly to switch. `switchTo().frame()` can receive `id`, `name` or `WebElement` as parameter

```
driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
```

If the frame takes time to load you can use explicit wait and `ExpectedCondition` [frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRefrence,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frameset/frame[2]")));
```

Comment: even if i do this way, i get the same error ```driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frameset/frame[2]"))```

Comment: got this error even tried for 50 seconds 
https://pastebin.com/60K8GEFP

Comment: @ChaudhryWaqas You are waiting for the frame after you switch to it, so it's not longer in the `driver` scope. Either switch to it using `driver.switchTo().frame` or use the explicit wait, but not both.

Comment: I am getting an error ```stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document``` using this code pastebin.com/QCHdxYdP

Comment: @ChaudhryWaqas The `frame` object is not part of the `driver` context after switching to the frame, so `mainFrame` is not valid anymore. After you switch to the frame just search for items in the regular way, no need to depend on the frame.

Comment: @ChaudhryWaqas and if you have new question please post new question, the comments are not meant for this.

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to traverse to the desired `frame` you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired frame to be available and switch to it.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

  - Using `name`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("mainFrame")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("element_name"))).click();
    ```
  - Using `xpath`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frame[@name='mainFrame' and contains(@src,'index1')]")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("element_xpath"))).click();
    ```

Comment: and how to find the elements inside that frame? I am getting an error ```stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document``` using this code https://pastebin.com/QCHdxYdP

Comment: @ChaudhryWaqas The screenshot you have provided doesn't includes the element which you want to click. The question doesn't includes the HTML of the element you want to click. Your code trials even doesn't. So I have provided a placeholder. let me know the status.

Comment: I want to click this http://prntscr.com/l8yhnu element but I get the error of timeout. And if I click on the 'PUCARS' menu item at the top of the page then i get  https://pastebin.com/DM87EwtJ

Comment: @ChaudhryWaqas _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _ExpectedConditions_. Debug your code through  `findElement()` inconjunction with `Thread.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.